# Database ERD diagram help? Weak Entities

Tags: database, analysis, erd

I have a question on weak entities.

Are they only formed from a Many to Many relationship?

This is my mates ERD for an assignment and I thought a weak entity can only be produced from a M-M relationships!

Thanks for the help
[ERD IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGhBr.jpg)

Comment: what do you mean by weak entities?

Comment: is an entity that cannot be uniquely identified by its attributes alone; therefore, it must use a foreign key in conjunction with its attributes to create a primary key.

Comment: so like a composite key?

Comment: I think so im not sure. In class we refer it to a Weak entity

Answer (score 0):

In that case yes. Generally you only form composite/weak entities to remove many to many relationships in a database design. However, there are other ways to remove many to many relationships without using a composite table.

See the article below

https://www.quora.com/Why-and-when-do-we-use-composite-primary-key

I think this will be of use to you.